# What would be the syntax to put into decltype(x) to specify the return type in this situation

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

I have the following function which creates a `std::vector` of iterators into another container:

```
template <typename T,
          template <typename, typename = std::allocator<T>> class Con>
std::vector<typename Con<T>::iterator> make_itervec(Con<T>& v)
{
    std::vector<typename Con<T>::iterator> itervec;
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    {
        itervec.push_back(i);
    }
    return itervec;
}
```

What I want to do is this:

```
template <typename T,
          template <typename, typename = std::allocator<T>> class Con>
auto make_itervec(Con<T>& v) -> decltype(x) // This line
{
    std::vector<typename Con<T>::iterator> itervec;
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    {
        itervec.push_back(i);
    }
    return itervec;
}
```

What do I put for `x` to get this to work?

Tried but failed attempts:

```
decltype(std::vector<typename Con<T>::iterator>)
decltype(std::vector<decltype(v)::iterator>)
```

(Also, I'm not an expert on this, so any other suggestions, comments are welcome! Thanks.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `std::vector<decltype(v)::iterator>` or `std::vector<decltype(v.begin())>`. Note that there's *no* `decltype` around the `std::vector` because that one already is a type, not a variable or expression. `decltype` is used only to get the type of an expression.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. However, using `std::vector<decltype(v)::iterator> ` didn't work (compile error), but `std::vector<typename Con<T>::iterator> ` did (using gcc 4.7.0).

Comment: @ildjarn: Nope, same error: `expected a type, got decltype (v)::iterator`.

Comment: @ildjarn: I was using `std::vector<decltype(v)::iterator> itervec = make_itervec(v);` in my code too which works fine, so definitely don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: you miss a typename before decltype(v)::

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: You're right! I also needed to pass by value for the function parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing too much work here. All you need to do is this:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<typename T::iterator> make_itervec(T& v)
{
    std::vector<typename T::iterator> itervec;

    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    {
        itervec.push_back(i);
    }

    return itervec;
}
```